# JSON Serialization issue dynamic tag format

Tags: serialization

I have following JSON which i am serializing using Json Serializer to read the value from JSON.

JSON

```
AccessTypes: {
AccessType: [
{
Services: "",
Type: "VDSL",
ProviderId: 1711339,
ServiceDetailExtData: "",
Serviceability: "Serviceable",
Provider: "LFC Chorus",
Priority: 500
},
{
Services: "",
Type: "UBA",
ProviderId: 1711339,
ServiceDetailExtData: "",
Serviceability: "Serviceable",
Provider: "LFC Chorus",
Priority: 500
}
]
}
```

I am using following class

```
public class AccessType
{            


public string Type { get; set; }


public string ProviderId { get; set; }
public string Serviceability { get; set; }
public string Provider { get; set; }
public string Priority { get; set; }
public string IntactStatus { get; set; }
}

public class AccessTypes
{   

public List<AccessType> AccessType { get; set; }
}
```

However sometimes my client is sending JSON which is not a array or list like below which has only single value.

```
AccessTypes: {
AccessType: 
{
Services: "",
Type: "VDSL",
ProviderId: 1711339,
ServiceDetailExtData: "",
Serviceability: "Serviceable",
Provider: "LFC Chorus",
Priority: 500
}   

}
```

Can you please help how to handle the tag which can be list or single value. one way i could think of is to replace tag with "[{" to get a list but there must be better way to do it.

```
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AccessTypes));
Stream str = response.GetResponseStream();
object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(str);
```

Comment: So what is the question? Also, JASON != JSON

Comment: dat3450 : Sorry just edited a question in proper format